# Regex para validar o mime type

Tags: php, regex

Qual seria a regex para validar esse mime types somente

- image/bmp
- image/gif
- image/x-icon
- image/pjpeg
- image/jpeg
- image/png

Quero fazer um sistema de upload de imagens **somente**, no caso desse mime types:

```
$verifyimg = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

if(!preg_match($pattern, $verifyimg['mime']){
        die("Só imagens!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desta forma, fica mais simples e mais fácil de ler:

```
if (strpos($verifyimg['mime'], 'image/') === false) {
    die("Só imagens!");
}
```

Utilizando regex:

```
if (!preg_match('/image\//',$verifyimg['mime'])) {
    die("Só imagens!");
}
```